# *Not* using navigation properties with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

Does anyone know if it's possible to *not* use the navigation properties feature of the entity framework for tables linked with a foreign key?

for example, if my client table has an AddressId, I want that AddressId in my model, I don't want it to have a .Address property.  But I have thus far been unable to figure out how to do this.

Comment: for those encountering this via search ... this was quite a while ago. Newer versions of the entity framework have no problems with this :-)

Comment: Are you sure? Because I've tried to do the same: I removed my navigation properties and left only scalar ones instead, but once I update model all navigation properties would be restored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can do this.  It's just that the designer won't help you very much.  Delete the navigation property, and add a scalar property for AddressId.  It will work, but you'll have to be careful about hitting Update Model in the designer, as it may try to "fix" things for you.  It's worth getting used to editing EDMX; it's not that bad.

Comment: What, specifically, are you looking for?  All of the early Entity Framework documentation was about editing the XML files manually, because there wasn't a designer at that point.  The only thing which has changed since then is the three separate files have been rolled into one EDMX file.

Comment: Does anybody know any solutions to remove/hide navigation properties and prevent further their restoration with model update, or even 3 years later I need to modify model manually? I don't mind to edit model manually but it is really huge right now, easier and faster to use designer =)

Comment: @JoAsakura, well, you can do it with code-first, or you can write an XML transform to remove them from EDMX and run that as a build action.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz, thx, I hoped that transform on build action wouldn't be an only solution =(

Answer (score 0):

In the designer, you can set the navigation properties as having Private getters/setters. While they will still be *there*, because Entity Framework (by default) does lazy loading, it won't actually retrieve any data from the database at runtime. And they won't respawn the next time you update the model from the database.